# QGIS 3.12 Masks

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

I just noticed a new entry in QGIS 3.12.0 layer properties: **Masks** [image]

However, it looks just blank, so I was wondering what it is for and how to use it. Searching the web and [QGIS changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelogs.html) did not return any results. The changelog for 3.12 seems to be not online yet.

I also enabled "Mask" within Labels-Menu, but still nothing to see:

[image]

Anyone has a clue about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find some information about the new entry and about more new features in QGIS 3.12 [here](https://github.com/pigreco/changelog312#selective-masking): 
it is a Changelog created with a GitHub filter by [Pigreco](https://github.com/pigreco).

Also, few more informations in the official temporary QGIS Changelog are at [this](https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.12/#selective-masking) page.

The new tool, if used in *Labels* creates a mask around the text that allows the label to stop overlap the underlying geometries and that makes it more readable. It is also possible to select which geometries will be masked.
It works in the same way with symbology.
[image]

**UPDATE**: official Changelog for QGIS 3.12 is now available at this [address](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/#)